# How to generate .edmx.diagram file using edmgen.exe?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, edmx-designer

Using the suggestion provided in [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/framework/data/adonet/ef/how-to-use-edmgen-exe-to-generate-the-model-and-mapping-files.md), I was able to generate the EDMX files needed for an ASP.net project. Using a command like:

```
"%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\edmgen.exe" /mode:fullgeneration    /c:"Data Source=%datasourceserver%; Initial Catalog=School; Integrated Security=SSPI"    /project:School /entitycontainer:SchoolEntities /namespace:SchoolModel /language:CSharp
```

But I don't know how to generate the accompanying **edmx.diagram** file that gets generated in Visual Studio if we create the EDMX via ADO.Net Data Model addition to existing project.

In the Solution Explorer, the file can be seen in a location like so:
[image]

The file can also be opened in Visual studio to see the Database structure in the form of a UML diagram like so:
[image]

Additionally the file generated for this gets shown like so:
[image]

I read the documentation on how to use edmgen.exe to generate the edmx files as well from the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/edm-generator-edmgen-exe).

I believe that the documentation to generate the edmx.document file has been missed in the Microsoft documentation and I have been unable to come up with a solution for this by myself. I have been stuck for quite some time on this problem and need help in resolving this.

I have used a similar mechanism to generate files needed in the [SQL2LINQ](https://github.com/ganeshkamath89/SQL2LINQConvertor) convertor project. Having this capability could help tremendously. Please help me.

**Edit 1:**
I have noticed that the edmx.diagram file has property like so. What I am not sure is if Visual Studio internally uses some other executable to generate the diagram files or if there is an un-documented flag that that can create the diagram files via command line. Please forgive my **Edit** this information was not avaialable while originally posting the question.

[image]

**Edit 2:**
All the steps involved in the process I use:

Step1: Copy my [resource files](https://github.com/ganeshkamath89/SQL2LINQConvertor/tree/master/SQL2LINQ/SQL2LINQ/Resources) to the folder where I require my edmx and dependency files to be generated.

Note: These files are dummy files and will be generated from the command line command I have pasted in the question.

Step 2: Run the command line command by navigating to the same path.

Step 3: After the command line is run, the connection string collected form the user will help in generating the necessary CSDL, SSDL and MSL files in the same directory. the files are then read and replaced int he edmx files that i have included in the resources folder in the link above.

Step 4: Run The textTransform.bat file to run the texttransform.exe from the Windows SDK path for Texttransform.exe.

**Observation:**
At this stage, 5 of the 6 files are created namely:

1. .context.tt
2. .context.cs
3. .Designer.cs
4. .tt
5. .cs

corresponding to the name provided by the user.

But the file .edmx.diagram is missing.

Code that does step 1 through 4:

```
internal class Globals {
    public static string EDMXworkingDirectory = @"C:\ERachana\EDMX\EDMXFiles\EDMXParts";
    public static bool isEDMXAlreadyGenerated = false;

    public static string Server = "",Database = "", UserName = "",Password = "";
    public static string ProjectName = "", UserDefinedObjectName = "_appdb", TemporaryDirectoryPath="";

    public static string GetSubstringBetweenStrings(string Full, string startMatch, string endMatch) {
        int pFrom = Full.IndexOf(startMatch) + startMatch.Length;
        int pTo = Full.LastIndexOf(endMatch);
        if (pTo > pFrom)
            return Full.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom);
        else
            return "";
    }

    public static void GenerateORMFiles() {
        string workingDirectory = EDMXworkingDirectory;
        if (!isEDMXAlreadyGenerated) {
            // Show Progress Bar here
            try {
                isEDMXAlreadyGenerated = true;
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\ERachana");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\ERachana\EDMX");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\ERachana\EDMX\EDMXFiles");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(workingDirectory);

                string CommandToCreateEDMXOnCommandLine = "\"%windir%\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\edmgen.exe\" /mode:fullgeneration /c:\"data source = "
                                    + Server + "; initial catalog = "
                                    + Database + "; user id = "
                                    + UserName + "; password = "
                                    + Password + "; MultipleActiveResultSets = True; persist security info = True; App = EntityFramework\" /project:DataModel /entitycontainer:DBContext /namespace:Models /language:CSharp & exit";

                string ResourcesDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\Resources\";
                string EDMXFileName = "DataModel.edmx";
                string ContextFileName = "DataModel.Context.tt";
                string TablesFileName = "DataModel.tt";

                string EdmxLocation = workingDirectory + @"\" + EDMXFileName;
                File.Copy(Path.Combine(ResourcesDirectory, EDMXFileName), EdmxLocation, true);
                File.Copy(Path.Combine(ResourcesDirectory, ContextFileName), workingDirectory + @"\" + ContextFileName, true);
                File.Copy(Path.Combine(ResourcesDirectory, TablesFileName), workingDirectory + @"\" + TablesFileName, true);
                using (var process = new Process()) {
                    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
                        WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory,
                        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized,
                        CreateNoWindow = true,
                        RedirectStandardInput = true,
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        FileName = "cmd.exe",
                        Verb = "runas"
                    };

                    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                    process.Start();
                    process.StandardInput.WriteLine(CommandToCreateEDMXOnCommandLine);
                    process.WaitForExit();
                    process.Close();
                    process.Dispose();
                }
                string text = File.ReadAllText(EdmxLocation);

                string c = "";
                c = parseSCMDLFiles(workingDirectory + @"\DataModel.ssdl", "Schema");
                text = text.Replace("###StorageModelsSchema", c);

                c = parseSCMDLFiles(workingDirectory + @"\DataModel.csdl", "Schema");
                text = text.Replace("###ConceptualModelsSchema", c);

                c = parseSCMDLFiles(workingDirectory + @"\DataModel.msl", "Mapping");
                text = text.Replace("###Mappings", c);

                File.WriteAllText(EdmxLocation, text);

                string[] fileToBeDeleted = Directory.GetFiles(workingDirectory);
                foreach (string filePath in fileToBeDeleted) {
                    if (filePath.Contains("DataModel.ObjectLayer.cs") || filePath.Contains("DataModel.Views.cs")) {
                        File.Delete(filePath);
                    } else {
                        if (filePath.ToLower().Contains(".edmx") || filePath.ToLower().Contains(".tt") || filePath.ToLower().Contains(".cs"))
                            continue;
                        File.Delete(filePath);
                    }
                }
                string location = @"C:\ERachana\EDMX";
                string TransformFileName = "transform_all.bat";
                File.Copy(Path.Combine(ResourcesDirectory, TransformFileName), location + @"\" + TransformFileName, true);
                string batFileCommand = "/C " + location + @"\" + TransformFileName;

                using (var process = new Process()) {
                    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() {
                        WorkingDirectory = location,
                        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized,
                        CreateNoWindow = true,
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        FileName = @"cmd.exe",
                        Verb = "runas",
                        Arguments = batFileCommand
                    };

                    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                    process.Start();
                    process.WaitForExit();
                    process.Close();
                    process.Dispose();
                }
            } catch {
                MessageBox.Show("Only Projects with MSSQL may be converted to Web Projects");
            } finally {
                // Close Progressbar here
            }
        }
    }

    public static string parseSCMDLFiles(string EDMXDirectoryFile, string tag) {
        List<string> lines = File.ReadLines(EDMXDirectoryFile).ToList();
        string content = "";
        bool flagEnable = false;
        foreach (string line in lines) {
            if (line.Contains("</" + tag + ">"))
                flagEnable = false;
            if (flagEnable == true)
                content += line + Environment.NewLine;
            if (line.Contains("<" + tag))
                flagEnable = true;
        }
        return content;
    }
}
```

Comment: What would you use this for? At runtime, the diagram file isn't used. At design time, it is, but a diagram is generated automatically if needed.

Comment: Hi @hvd. In ASP.net project I need this diagram to show a visualization of database tables. The output of my tool, will need to be customized by other people who are working on the same project and it will grately help if they can see the visualization as they develop.

Comment: Hi @hvd. Is there a way to independantly generate the diagram at design time if we delete the diagram file manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**

To make the `edmx` designer show the diagrams, you can use either of the following options:

- Having `<Designers></Designers>` tag in `edmx` file.
- Having `.edmx.designer` file with following contents and child of `.edmx` file:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <edmx:Edmx Version="3.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
    <edmx:Designer>
      <edmx:Diagrams>

      </edmx:Diagrams>
    </edmx:Designer>
  </edmx:Edmx>
  ```

**Long Answer**

[`EdmGen.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/edm-generator-edmgen-exe) will not generate `edmx` for you, but it generates all data that you need to create an `edmx` file yourself. You can simply create edmx file by mixing those `csdl`, `ssdl` and `msl`.

Also about the diagram file, you should know `edmx.diagram` file is not necessary. When you create the `edmx` file, with empty `<Diagrams></Diagrams>` tag, the first time that you open the edmx file in designer, Visual Studio will create the content for the tag for you. Then if for any reason you like to have ot in separate file, you can simply right click on design surface of the edmx and choose `Move Diagrams to Separate File`.

You can follow the following steps to create an `edmx` file manually (or by code) yourself:

**1-** Run `EdmGen`

```
"%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\edmgen.exe" /mode:fullgeneration  /c:"Data Source=SERVERNAME; Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME;Integrated Security=SSPI" /project:PROJECT /entitycontainer:CONTAINER /namespace:NAMESPACE /language:CSharp /targetversion:4.5
```

**2-** Create an edmx file with following contents.

Please note that the `edmx` content which I used in this post, is based on `/targetversion:4.5` switch.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="3.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
  <!-- EF Runtime content -->
  <edmx:Runtime>
    <!-- SSDL content -->
    <edmx:StorageModels>
    $SSDL$
    </edmx:StorageModels>
    <!-- CSDL content -->
    <edmx:ConceptualModels>
    $CSDL$
    </edmx:ConceptualModels>
    <!-- C-S mapping content -->
    <edmx:Mappings>
    $MSL$
    </edmx:Mappings>
  </edmx:Runtime>
  <!-- EF Designer content (DO NOT EDIT MANUALLY BELOW HERE) -->
  <Designer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
    <Connection>
      <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
        <DesignerProperty Name="MetadataArtifactProcessing" Value="EmbedInOutputAssembly" />
      </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
    </Connection>
    <Options>
      <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
        <DesignerProperty Name="ValidateOnBuild" Value="true" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="EnablePluralization" Value="true" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="IncludeForeignKeysInModel" Value="true" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="UseLegacyProvider" Value="false" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="CodeGenerationStrategy" Value="None" />
      </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
    </Options>
    <!-- Diagram content (shape and connector positions) -->
    <Diagrams></Diagrams>
  </Designer>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

**3-** Replace the placeholders which you have in edmx with content of the following files (without `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`):

- `$SSDL$` should be replaced with content of the `ssdl` file.
- `$CSDL$` should be replaced with content of the `csdl` file.
- `$MSL$` should be replaced with content of the `msl` file.

**Note**

`.edmx.designer` is optional and it's enough to have an `<Diagrams></Diagrams>` tag in `edmx` like what I shared above, then the first time that you open Visual Studio, the diagram will be created for you automatically. Also for any reason if you like to have diagram i a separate file, you can simply create an empty diagram file, which will be filled by VS at the first time that you open edmx:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="3.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
  <edmx:Designer>
    <edmx:Diagrams>

    </edmx:Diagrams>
  </edmx:Designer>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Comment: Hi @Reza Aghaei, Thank you for looking into the problem. I believe I am already doing the step 1, 2 and 3 in the code. I wanted to know if you know some way to fill the `<Diagrams></Diagrams>` tag above with the appropriate content and if there is a way to generate the.edms.Diagram file. the difference is that i am using `###StorageModelsSchema` instead of `$SSDL$` to replace the respective sections

Comment: Hi @GaneshKamath-'CodeFrenzy' You don't need to fill the diagram section. It's just some UI information and will be filled automatically by VS the first time that you open the file in VS.

Comment: Hi @Reza Aghaei, For some reason, VS does not generate this in the Project that I generate. I think there is some way to calculate the PointX, PointY co-ordinates that are displayed int he xml format shown in the question above.

Comment: I don't say VS will generate `edmx.diagram`. It will generate the contents for `<Diagrams></Diagrams>`.  `edmx.diagram` is not necessary. What's the usage of `.edmx.diagram` for you. It's enough to open edmx in Visual Studio to be able to see the diagram, without having any `edmx.diagram`.

Comment: In fact if you right click in design surface of `edmx` and click `Move Diagram to separate files` then it will generate `.edmx.diagram` file and moves the content of `<Diagrams></Diagrams>` to that file.

Comment: okay, let me try one more time and add more details to the question in case that solves my problem. At the end of the day, I want to generate the .edmx.diagram via comman line and not via Visual Studio

Comment: I should emphasis that `edmx.designer` is not necessary and you can see the diagram, without having `edmx.designer`, just by having an empty `<Designers></Designers>` tag in `edmx` file. It's the important point.

Comment: Hi @Reza Aghaei, I know that it is optional. That is exactly what has kept our project going for the past 4 months. But There is a lot of push to make the EDMX part complete and have all features, as if when developed from scratch through visual studio. That is why I am asking this on Stackoverflow. Trying your solution with empty design tags.

Comment: I see, but Visual Studio also creates the diagrams at the first time that you open edmx.

Comment: The short answer is, you should have either of `<Diagrams></Diagrams>` empty tag in edmx or the content which I shared as `edmx.diagram` file content.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the schema @Reza Aghaei, somehow it is not creating the file even after adding it directly to the project and adding the tag `/targetversion:4.5`

Comment: You're welcome. For me using VS 2017 (version 15.5.4) it works properly. I shared the exact steps what I'm using.

Comment: The importance of `/targetversion:4.5` is just because of the schema versions and urls.

Comment: Oh, I am working on VS 2015. Sorry forgot to mention.

Comment: While the version of VS may be important, but before making any assumption, make sure you are following the exact steps correctly.